# How to put a line from a file into a table (variable)

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following file

```
Durand 12 9 14
Lucas 8 11 4
Martin 9 12 1
```

I need to display the name and the average of the three other with a function. The function part is easy.

I thought I could get line by line with:

```
head -i notes | tail -1
```

and then put the result of the command in a table in order to access it

```py
table=(head -i notes | tail -1)
echo "${table[0]} averge : moy ${table[1]} ${table[2]} ${table[3]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use three important concepts to approach a problem like this.

1. Iterate over a file
2. Store values as variables
3. Do math to variables

A good way to read a file line by line is with a `while` loop:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < notes
```

Notice how we use a file redirect `<` to treat the file as standard input. `read` consumes one full line at a time. Let's expand on that in order to store separate variables.

```
while read name a b c; do echo $name $a $b $c; done < notes
```

Now let's get math involved. You could use an external program like `bc`, but that's inefficient if we don't need floating point math (decimals). Bash has math built in!

```
while read name a b c; do echo $name $(( (a + b + c) / 3 )); done < notes
```

Like you said, the function part is easy :)

---

awk one liner:

```
awk '{print $1, ($2+$3+$4)/3}' notes
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I would never thought of that.
But just to answer my question, is there a way to store the line in a table ?

Comment: Also why do you have to put $ (a + b + c) / 3 between ((   )) in order to work ?

Comment: @DjallelEddineBOUAKAZ `((` is for Arithmetic Evaluation. See `man bash`, `/^ARI`